# How do you save a state in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

As you might know from my previous posts, I am developing a chrome extension. I have a button that toggles the extension on & off, and this button's state is saved when you click out of the extension. You can see the code for this below:

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="style_popup.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="mainpage.html" target = "_blank" class="active">View My Dashboard</a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="center">[Title]</h1>
    <button id="buttonclick" class="button">Enable Control</button>
    <br> <img src="green_circle.PNG" height="140" width="150" id="centerimage"> <br>
    <p class="center" id="status"> [Title] is running! </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
let changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');

chrome.storage.sync.get('color', function(data) {
  changeColor.style.backgroundColor = data.color;
  changeColor.setAttribute('value', data.color);
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('buttonclick');
    // onClick's logic below:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        handler();
    });
});
function handler()
{
    chrome.storage.local.get({count: 0}, function (result) {
        var count = result.count;
        var buttonState = document.getElementById('buttonclick');
        var imageState = document.getElementById('centerimage');
        var status = document.getElementById('status');
        if (count == 0) {
            buttonState.style.backgroundColor = "#75ad0a";
            buttonState.innerHTML = "Enabled";
            imageState.src = "green_circle.PNG";
            status.innerHTML = "[Title] is running!"
            count = 1;
        }
        else {
            buttonState.style.backgroundColor = "#AA2B0E";
            buttonState.innerHTML = "Disabled";
            imageState.src = "red_circle.png";
            status.innerHTML = "[Title] is not running!"
            count = 0;
        }
        chrome.storage.local.set({count: count});
    });
}
```

However, I am running into a bit of a pickle. I want to make it such that if a user were to click the button (thereby disabling the extension), exit the chrome extension, and then click back into it, it would still show as disabled. With my current case, however, it will just display the "Enable Control" and "[Title] is running" every time they open the extension UNTIL the user clicks the button. In other words, it would be reset & and I want the state to be preserved. As you can see from my popup.js, I've already written code that saves the state of a variable, but I am unsure how to actually make the state be preserved in the HTML. I would greatly appreciate any help, thanks!